# Java web-app running from tomcat spikes CPU to 100% and becomes useless

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, cpu-usage

First of all thank you for reading this question. We have a Java webapp which gets hit 15req/s (tomcat access log) and around 60 to 80 users from Google analytics. This app does get very resource hungry sometimes, then we have to restart it to make it to operational state. We need to restart this every second day obviously and sometimes everyday. CPU usage is not in specific time pattern. Sometimes if we get a little bit higher traffic, it spikes but that we understand. But sometimes CPU spikes to 100 in unusual traffic, when almost zero traffic on the site.

**java version "1.8.0_65"**

**Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)**

**Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)**

**Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.30**

Catalina output is turned off by debug=0.

Thread dump on HEAVY CPU USAGE:

```
15.txt-
15.txt-"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407c800 nid=0xb85 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36611c0000]
15.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
15.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
15.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
15.txt- at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
--
16.txt-
16.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
16.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
16.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
16.txt- at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
16.txt- - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
17.txt-
17.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
17.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
17.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
17.txt- at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
17.txt- - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
18.txt-
18.txt-"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407c800 nid=0xb85 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36611c0000]
18.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
18.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
18.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
18.txt- at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
--
22.txt-
22.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
22.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
22.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
22.txt- at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
22.txt- - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
24.txt-
24.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
24.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
24.txt- at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
24.txt- at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
24.txt- - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
3.txt-
3.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
3.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
3.txt-  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
3.txt-  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
3.txt-  - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
5.txt-
5.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
5.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
5.txt-  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
5.txt-  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
5.txt-  - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
x.txt-15.txt-
x.txt-15.txt-"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407c800 nid=0xb85 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36611c0000]
x.txt:15.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-15.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-15.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
x.txt-15.txt-   at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
--
x.txt-16.txt-
x.txt-16.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
x.txt:16.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-16.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-16.txt-   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
x.txt-16.txt-   - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
x.txt-17.txt-
x.txt-17.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
x.txt:17.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-17.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-17.txt-   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
x.txt-17.txt-   - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
x.txt-18.txt-
x.txt-18.txt-"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407c800 nid=0xb85 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36611c0000]
x.txt:18.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-18.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-18.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
x.txt-18.txt-   at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
--
x.txt-22.txt-
x.txt-22.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
x.txt:22.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-22.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-22.txt-   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
x.txt-22.txt-   - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
x.txt-24.txt-
x.txt-24.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
x.txt:24.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-24.txt-   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-24.txt-   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
x.txt-24.txt-   - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
x.txt-3.txt-
x.txt-3.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
x.txt:3.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-3.txt-    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-3.txt-    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
x.txt-3.txt-    - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
--
x.txt-5.txt-
x.txt-5.txt-"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f36a407f000 nid=0xb86 in Object.wait() [0x00007f36610bf000]
x.txt:5.txt:   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
x.txt-5.txt-    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
x.txt-5.txt-    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
x.txt-5.txt-    - locked <0x00000006c65c8060> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
```

These are the BLOCKED states from thread dump.

RUNNABLE STATE: http://pastebin.com/Uv1j3yrh

I am stuck at investigating this issue. How can i go deep?

Comment: You need to look at all the `-exec-` threads. They are the ones that are processing and consuming CPU. Most of them seem to be Hibernate or Regex parsing. They are all request processing threads, so "zero traffic" is definitely not the case. Did you look at the Tomcat Status page to see all the incomplete requests? You might also need to get a deeper stack trace of those `-exec-` threads, to see why there are so many doing regex, because you might have some very badly written expressions.

Comment: P: Parse and prepare request S: Service F: Finishing R: Ready K: Keepalive

From status page there are a lot of "R", what is that mean ? But this scenario is after a clean restart of the app. 

SCREENSHOT: https://s14.postimg.org/vbeex5y35/afterre.png

@Andreas

Comment: Those are just threads that are waiting on work to do. They take no CPU.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the Tomcat process using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) ?

Comment: I have tried VisualVM. But couldn't go deep. I mean i was confused about what to look there .... :( @Saheed

Comment: Your first step would be to try and replicate the issues you are experiencing in your development environment. In other words, you will need to using something like Apache JMeter to execute load tests against the Tomcat server running on your development machine, then use the VisualVM tool to connect to the Tomcat process to observe where there are spikes while the JMeter load tests are running.

Comment: Thank You everyone. But the problem is i couldn't create the same scenario in my Development machine. :(

Now i have another type of data:
The CPU usage is happened by FGC.

When it happens i see "0" in both survival space. @Saheed

Comment: You need to provide additional info. Like critical sections of your code that is causing high memory and CPU usage. I believe the first commenter above mentioned that there is heavy regex use in the code. Start by getting help with refactoring that.